# How can all the Workspace windows be enumerated in a Pharo workspace?

Tags: enumeration, pharo, class-hierarchy

I want to list all the Workspaces windows in a in a Pharo window. When I shift click a Workspace window the item selected is usually a PluggableTextMorph or a TextMorphForEditView. When it is a PluggableTextMorph it owns a TextMorphforEditView which was not picked by the click.

Inspecting or exploring the hierarchy shows that is owned by a SystemWindow of a Model Workspace further up the hierachy.

What code do I need to first of all list all TextMorphforEditView(s) in the system and lookup the ownership hierarchy to determine whether the model of the SystemWindow is a Workspace or a Transcript?

Answer (score 1):

To get all Workspaces you can simply explore or inspect:

```
Workspace allInstances
```

If you are interested in all windows containing Workspaces, you can explore or inspect:

```
| listOfWindows |

listOfWindows := Workspace allInstances collect: 
    [:eachWorkspace | eachWorkspace containingWindow]
```

Comment: now it seems to be `Context allInstances` -- pharo 11th.